# Meaning of JVM Xms paramater

Tags: java, jvm

What does the JVM -Xms paramater do?

I expected the process stack of the jvm process to occupy atleast the minimum configured Xms value. But this doesn't seem to be the case. **Why doesn't the process status of the jvm already occupy the minimum configured heap value?**

**Is it that the memory will grow to the minimum configured value without the GC ever running?**

Edit: This question is asking more that what is explained here [What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

Comment: These are parameters that control the heap size, not the stack size.

Comment: The minimum heap size doesn't fill the heap with objects. The `-Xms` sets the initial size for the heap.

Comment: Please reword the question, and move the bolded part up into the question subject instead of embedded inside another question which appears to duplicate the closed question.